# onclick closing other onclicks

Tags: javascript, css, popup

I have multiple div elements on my page, which have the display switch function .

```
 onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'" 
onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display=''}else{document.getElementById('spoiler2') .style.display='none'}"
```

I am looking for a way to close each other opened element when opening a new one, so that only one can stay open.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your HTML, and/or try to make fiddle.

Comment: You prefer javascript or you can do this through JQuery ?

Comment: both javascript and jquery work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard to understand without looking at your html, but you can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#light").on("click", function() {
  $("#spoiler2").hide();
   $(this).show();
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I was just looking for onclick hide function, been up way too long so my social skills are sleeping at the moment xD